# How to import only mail subject from another account (without body and attachments)

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account and also another mail account. I need the following functionality: when a mail message arrives to the other account, with specific subject or from specific senders, I would like to receive a message in Gmail without the message body and attachments.

The message should also have some custom text added to the original subject (like "from mail001: "). I know there are labels in Gmail, but I need it directly in the subject field.

I do not want Gmail to import the whole message, only the subject, perhaps sender and other header fields (subject being the most important).

I cannot assume anything about the other mail possibilities or API.

Is it doable at all?